# Need some with a regular expression for C# returning one or more multiple matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have a tag system
the tag will look something like this

```
{Value:12345}
or
{ValueOR[null]:12345}
```

I need the 
12345
and the second if it exists, all characters between the brackets
the number must always exist

I tried this:

```
{Value:[0-9]+}|{ValueOR\[(.*)\]:[0-9]+}
```

But that's not it of course :)

In the example above: If the text was '{Value:12345}' I want to see the "12345" if the text was {ValueOR[null]:12345} I would like to see both "12345" and "NULL"

for example I am building a tag replacement system  to fill dynamic comboboxes
the field in the database will have something like 'exec sp_GetComoboValue {value:12345}' the value '12345' refers to another filter field I have on the form. if it goes and looks up 12345 and it has the value '125' I want to change the string to exec sp_GetComoboValue 125. if the field 12345 returns nothing. the sp cannot execute; if the tag {valueOR[NULL]:12345}'  then it would be exec sp_GetComoboValue NULL. Note the null is arbitrary I don't care what the string is between the '[' and the ']' if the OR[????] exists I want to use it.

In case anyone is interested I went with the following solution
`{(?Value|Caption|Global)(OR[(?(.))])?:(?(.))}`
this allows three types of tags, to get the type, or, and field id from each.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure you I've got your point but what you actually wanna print out?

Comment: http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: `\{Value(OR\[.*\])?:[0-9]+\}`

Comment: **"and the second"** which second ?

Comment: In the example above: If the text was '{Value:12345}' I want to see the "12345" if the text was {ValueOR[null]:12345} I would like to see both "12345" and "NULL"

Comment: is null always 'null' or is it something also a number? ex:  {ValueOR[555]:12345}

Comment: Is using regex mandatory or are another solutions also acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
\{Value(OR\[(.*)\])?:(.*)\}
```

Comment: Awesome Thank you, you just saved me from having to work all night!!

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
{Value:(\d+)}\s*or\s*{ValueOR\[null\]:(\d+)?
```

For C# basic idea is this, you may want to check if Groups[2] is set as it is optional

```
Regex yourRegex = new Regex(@"{Value:(\d+)}\s*or\s*{ValueOR\[null\]:(\d+)?", RegexOptions.Multiline);
string id1 = yourRegex.Match(yourstring).Groups[1].Value;
string id2 = yourRegex.Match(yourstring).Groups[2].Value;
```